# Lubuntu VM - how to make external monitor on left side of primary monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, lubuntu, display, virtualization, monitor

I am using lubuntu as a virtual machine and my host OS is windows 8 and I connected an external monitor and it is to the right of my primary monitor. How do I change it so that it is to the left of my primary monitor? I tried going to desktop settings but couldn't find anything. I also went to Presferences -> Display Settings and it said 'The following monitors are detected:' and showed 'Virtual1' and 'Virtual2' and gave me the option to turn them off / on, change their resolution and refresh rate, but I am not able to pick which side the monitor appears. How do I change it so that my external monitor is on the left side of my primary monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Well, for me, I was running lubuntu as a virtual machine and my host OS was windows 8 so I just went into the host OS display options and changed the monitor display settings from there and it took effect in the VM as well.